# How can I autowire my beans in Spring Cloud Functions in Azure?

Tags: java, spring, azure, dependency-injection, spring-cloud-function

Is there any way I can do dependency injection in a Spring Cloud Function that will be running in Azure ?

For [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/getting-started-with-spring-cloud-function-in-azure?source=recommendations):

```
package com.example;

import com.example.model.Greeting;
import com.example.model.User;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;
import org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.FunctionInvoker;

import java.util.Optional;

public class HelloHandler extends FunctionInvoker<User, Greeting> {

    @FunctionName("hello")
    public HttpResponseMessage execute(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
        ExecutionContext context) {
        User user = request.getBody()
                           .filter((u -> u.getName() != null))
                           .orElseGet(() -> new User(
                               request.getQueryParameters()
                                      .getOrDefault("name", "world")));
        context.getLogger().info("Greeting user name: " + user.getName());
        return request
            .createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
            .body(handleRequest(user, context))
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build();
    }
}
```

How can I use the `@Autowired` annotation here ? Its evaluated during runtime, right.

**How can I achieve dependency injection ?**

I need DI to inject mocks in place my actual beans during testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staring with Spring Cloud Function `4.0.0` you can use dependency injections like this:

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

import com.example.model.Greeting;
import com.example.model.User;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpMethod;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpResponseMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpStatus;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class HelloHandler {

    @Autowired    
    Function<Mono<User>, Mono<Greeting>> hello;
    
    @FunctionName("hello")
    public HttpResponseMessage execute(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {
        User user = request.getBody()
                .filter((u -> u.getName() != null))
                .orElseGet(() -> new User(
                        request.getQueryParameters()
                                .getOrDefault("name", "world")));
        
        context.getLogger().info("DI Greeting user name: " + user.getName());
        
        return request
                .createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(hello.apply(Mono.just(user)).block())
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
    }
}
```

E.g. no need to extend `FunctionInvoker`. Just mark the hander as `@Component` and inject all necessary dependencies you need to use in your functions.

You can check this [PR](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/hello-spring-function-azure/pull/39) that updates the same example code. Note that the [PR code](https://github.com/tzolov/hello-spring-function-azure/tree/di-integration) significantly simplifies the pom configurations as well.

**Update:**

This is a new feature recently released by the Azure Java Function Runtime and supported by Spring Cloud Function 4.0.0+.

Here are the related blog [Spring Cloud Function for Azure Function](https://spring.io/blog/2023/02/24/spring-cloud-function-for-azure-function), the updated [ref. doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/4.0.2-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/azure.html#_microsoft_azure) and few [samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/main/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-azure-di-samples).

The [azure-functions-core-tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools) version `4.0.5030` or newer is required.

Comment: How does this work ? When Azure actually invokes the function I believe it does something like : `new HelloHandler().execute()` ? How does Azure functions know how to resolve Spring `@Autowired` ?

Comment: Does it the Azure Function Runtime actually check if its a Spring Component and then somehow access the Spring Beans ?

Comment: Please explain how to do the testing in local. But before that please explain how the runtime actually resolves dependencies ?

Comment: Azure runtime doesn't know about Spring nor auto-wiring. It only knows that classes with @FunctionName annotated methods are function classes. 
So before it invokes the function methods (`execute` in this example), Azure allows (as a new feature) to hook a callback service that provided with the function class creates an instance for this class. Then Azure uses the instance to invoke function.
SCF 4.0.0+ implements the hook service and uses it to create the Spring Context for the provided class and perform the auto-wiring.
This is just an overview. A detailed blog entry is on the way.

Comment: Waiting for the detailed blog. If you are writing it please do let me know. What is `SCF 4.0.0+` ? Is it Spring Cloud Foundry ? Because that does not make much sense. Where is this hook function implemented ? In the Spring Framework somewhere ? This is so cool.

Comment: Yes SCF stands for [Spring Cloud Function](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function) and the `spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure` module is where the hook is implemented.
The related blog (as well as the updated SCF azure adapter doc) are ready actually. We have just been waiting for Microsoft to release the azure-functions-core-tools so that one can run local testing without need to manual adjustments of the environments. I hope that Azure will make this release soon.

Comment: fyi, here is the updated SCF/Azure adapter doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/4.0.2-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/azure.html

Comment: @ng.newbie here is the blog [https://spring.io/blog/2023/02/24/spring-cloud-function-for-azure-function](https://spring.io/blog/2023/02/24/spring-cloud-function-for-azure-function), the updated [ref. doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/4.0.2-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/azure.html#_microsoft_azure) and few [samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/main/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-azure-di-samples).

Comment: Also, Microsoft has just released [azure-functions-core-tools#4.0.5030](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases/tag/4.0.5030). Just updated your local toolkit and you can test locally as well.

Comment: I like the blog, but however it tells me nothing about how the Spring Context is resolved. There is just a vague statement "Having the adapter on the classpath activates the Azure Java Worker integration."

I like all the Spring blogs but however I am yet to see Spring documentation which goes into a bit of the internals.

Comment: Found the hook in `AzureFunctionInstanceInjector` (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/adapter/azure/AzureFunctionInstanceInjector.java)

Comment: Can you have a look at this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097386/spring-azure-function-failure-exception-illegalargumentexception-when-running